# Set latency for OnTouchListener when using it for drag and drop actions

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, onclicklistener, ontouchlistener, tablerow

I Have a project with table rows that can be moved to other Tables via Drag and Drop. I want these Rows to be highlightable as well, I set focusable and focusableontouchmode to true and the background to list_selector_background and made the row clickable. without the OnTouchListener selecting works fine but if i set the onTouchListener to the row it starts a drag and drop process immediately when i click on it. Is there a way to set the latency of the onTouchListener up so that it can distinguish between a single click and the start of a draganddrop process? (so that you have to hold the click on the row to start dragging)

The OnTouchListener:

```
private final class MyTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
            DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(
                    view);
            view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

The Row:

```
teacherRow.setId(tid);
teacherRow.setBackgroundResource(drawable.list_selector_background);
teacherRow.setFocusable(true);
teacherRow.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
teacherRow.setClickable(true);
teacherRow.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
```

I also tried to solve it with an OnClickListener on the Row but that didnt work either

Comment: You should provide some of your code. It will be helpful.

Comment: touch listnener code added

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to set the latency of the onTouchListener up so that it
>   can distinguish between a single click and the start of a draganddrop
>   process?

I'm not sure I completely understood what you want to do but have a look at the code below:

```
        public boolean onTouch(final View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (view.isPressed()) {
                            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
                            DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(
                                    view);
                            view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
                            v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }
                    }

                }, (long) (1.5 * ViewConfiguration.getLongPressTimeout()));
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Where `mHandler` is a simple `Handler` instance.